# iMac Internet Surfing Issue

Tags: network, wifi, safari, imac, google-chrome

I have an iMac (Retina 5K 27", Mid 2015) with OS X Yosemite v10.10.2. I am connecting to my network with a cable but when i type an address or refresh the page, the loading icon appears in favicon, but it keeps turning forever and the page is doing nothing. I have to refresh or re-enter the site like 4 or 5 times to make it work. Sometimes even that is not enough. I am pressing stop several times and refreshing it to make it work.

1) I have encountered this situation both on Chrome and Safari. Don't think this is browser based.

2) I have switched from cable to Wi-Fi but same problem still continuous.

3) There are 7 machines in my network, 6 Windows + 1 Mac, but Windows computers are not experiencing this issue. Everything is fine for them.

4) We are not using a server in the network. Computers are directly accessing the switch or access point and those are reaching the modem directly.

This really annoying. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Check your network connection.

- Open System Preferences
- Click on Network, on the button Assist me... and then on diagnostics.
- Choose your Network e.g. LAN and check the connection.

If you have at this point no problems

- Click on the Network Window on the button Options.. and to the DNS Register.
- Check if any other DNS entries are there unless the standard entries from your Router.
- If additional entries you can delete them if you click on the minus (-) button below.

Check if the problem exists.

If you have any Network Software or (bad Antivirus) on your mac, please disable temporary.

Clear the System Caches in that order...

1. Restart your mac and hold down the shift-Key during startup.
2. This will start in the Safe Mode. You no need to login, after the startup is done, you can restart your mac.
3. During startup hit the buttons Command + ALT (Option) + R to boot into internet Recovery.
4. Choose from there Disk Utility, check and repair the permissions of your System drive.
5. Restart in normal Mode and check if the problem exists.